# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error on decrypting with RSA and Base64 encoding

Tags: encryption, micronaut

I have following program for encrypting and decrypting data.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.security.*;


public class EncryptionUtil {

    static final String SECRET_ALGO = "RSA";
    static final String CIPHER_TOKENIZER_TRANSFORMER = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
    static final int KEY_SIZE = 1024;

    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen;
    KeyPair pair;
    Cipher cipher;

    @Inject
    public EncryptionUtil(){
        try{
            keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(SECRET_ALGO);
            keyPairGen.initialize(KEY_SIZE);
            pair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TOKENIZER_TRANSFORMER);
        }catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot Build Encryption Utils with given params");
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String encrypted) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pair.getPrivate());
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(new Base64().decode(encrypted.getBytes())));
        } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new FiveXXServiceException(e.getMessage(), ErrorCode.DECRYPTION_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pair.getPublic());
            return new String(new Base64().encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes())));
        } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new FiveXXServiceException(e.getMessage(), ErrorCode.ENCRYPTION_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

}
```

Here I am getting the following exception while decrypting the data

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
```

couple of different syntax i tried but nothing worked..
any idea what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: When you create an `EncryptionUtil` instance, a new key pair is created. Decryption works as long as you use the same `EncryptionUtil` instance for encryption and decryption, because then the public key for encryption and the private key for decryption belong to the *same* key pair. As soon as encryption and decryption use different `EncryptionUtil` instances, the code does not work anymore, because then the public key for encryption and the private key for decryption do belong to *different* key pairs, so they are are not related anymore.

Comment: @Topaco i actually need to save this data in db..what could be the possible approach to get correct decrypted data every time?

Comment: I actually explained it: If you encrypt with a public key, the corresponding private key must be used for decryption, i.e. you must store this key (securely) in some form. Asymmetric encryption (like RSA) is mostly used for exchanging symmetric keys in hybrid encryption. Maybe symmetric encryption (like AES) is better suited for your needs. You can find many posts on the web about the different types of encryption.